# Vue.js 2, do I have to use multiple v-models for to bind values to a form component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making this basic form component with first name, last name, email, phone number input fields, but I'm trying to pass to it the user object to prefill it and change the data using one v-model.

My code.

```
 <div> 
   <myForm v-model="user" />
 </div>
```

The way I saw multiple values being handled online.

```
 <div> 
   <myForm v-model:firstName="user.firstName" v-model:lastName="user.lastName"
v-model:email="user.email" v-model:phone="user.phone" />
 </div>
```

Is there a way to handle an object being passed through a v-model and updating it, or do I have to list the things I'd like changed in that object with that second code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below approach to create a reactive model.

```html
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Firstname"
    v-model="reactiveValue.firstName"
  />
  <!-- Your form code -->
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
      }),
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    reactiveValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.$emit("input", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Then call it like:

```html
 <myForm v-model="user" />
```

It uses computed properties to create reactive data.

Comment: this definitely helped, but I'm also curious how I would go around passing a boolean value that checks whether the dialog form should be visible or not.

Comment: send it in another property.